# Programming microcontroller products

Tags: microcontroller

I've tried searching Google and was wondering what language microcontrollerare programmed in? Can you use Java? Like say on an amplifier you have a menu to increase or lower bass and treble, displaying firmware version and so on. I'm assuming they would be flashed with a special tool.

Also is Java or C++ the better language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that you are still relatively new to the subject. Unfortunately, I can't give you a direct answer, because the topic of hardware-oriented programming on embedded systems is a very deep and complex topic in computer science.

But in general: When programming microcontrollers (or microchips, as you call them) there is usually not much object-oriented programming. Things like generic programming styles etc. you search in vain. The rule is: lean, fast and direct languages that allow a reasonable amount of freedom in programming (e.g. C, C++) are used here. Java (or C#, if the architecture with .Net Frameworks allows it at all) are not suitable for this.

But this does not mean that it is not possible to develop such applications with Java and C#. I had the pleasure to write a highly available application in C# for a microcontroller. This is possible, but not pleasant.

If you want to get first impressions in this field of computer science, I recommend to buy a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.amazon.de/NinkBox-Raspberry-originaler-unterst%C3%BCtzt-Verbessertes/dp/B07ZV9C6QF/ref=sr_1_17_sspa?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=35JP6DB9PFQP2&dchild=1&keywords=raspberry%20pi&qid=1607514132&s=computers&sprefix=ras%2Ccomputers%2C193&sr=1-17-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExVk9ZRUpFWFZHWkFUJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMTIzNTczMUwyWlZITllCTzE3TSZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwNjI2OTA2MjBHMkc2MkEyTjU4TiZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX210ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=) and develop your first programs on it. Based on this you can then add [additional hardware](https://www.amazon.de/SUNFOUNDER-Raspberry-Projekten-Elektronik-Programmierung/dp/B07WYX8M76/ref=sr_1_9?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=2NYXLITZPMPUU&dchild=1&keywords=raspberry%20pi%20starterset&qid=1607514256&s=computers&sprefix=raspberry%20pi%20st%2Ccomputers%2C532&sr=1-9) and program it (e.g. an LCD display or a few sensors). From then on you can jump to other microcontrollers (like the STM32).

Greetings

Comment: Ahh thank you so much for that, guess it'll be worth taking a C++ course instead of Java!